# Sequence Diagrams in XMI format to pseudo code

Tags: java, parsing, uml, altova, xmi

I have Sequence Diagrams exported from Altova UModel Tool in `XMI 2.1 for UML 2.2` format. I need to generate pseudo code of the Sequence Diagram. Are there any specific java libraries (DOM?) which can be used to parse XMI, which can help to generate pseudo code.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I guess you're lost here. OMG has published XMI formats (see their website). But implementations of that differ from tool to tool (slightly but significantly enough to hinder mutual im-/export).

Comment: I am not looking for inter tool im/exp. I just want XMI to some pseudo code. OMG os ok, but I don't want to code and parse everything

Comment: I know, that's why I said "you're lost". I once tried tried to parse XMI for some reason and found me left alone. Likely just tool vendors have libs which do do not give away. With Enterprise Architect I would import the XMI and use the API to interpret the SD.

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unified_Modeling_Language_tools) lists some open source `UML` tools written in `Java`. Serious `UML` modeling tool **must** support some kind of `XMI` model round-tripping. I'd try to rip and reuse `XMI` manipulation library used by [Modeliosoft's Modelio](https://www.modelio.org/index.php) as it was the most reasonable candidate in the free-space when I was researching it a year ago. You can go and get the source at http://forge.modelio.org/projects